# Switching from parallel running tests to serial test execution use testng

Tags: java, parallel-processing, testng

I have a large number of tests that run in parallel. In After method I have a check that fail when running tests in parallel. Is it possible at the time of launch AfterMethod to switch to sequential launch of tests?

Comment: Please include code or more details like what causes it to fail. [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.